# how to take sum of column with same id neo4j

Tags: neo4j, sum, cypher

I want to get the `id` of a user who has the sum of `order count` we have passed in the query.

Example:

consider this the below data

```
urid        oc
1           2
1           3
1           0
2           1
3           6
1           4
3           1
```

I want the following output

1. When I pass total count as `9` it should return urid `1`
2. When I pass total count as `1` it should return urid `2`
3. When I pass total count as `7` it should return urid `3`

I have tried with the following Cypher Query. It is not working as execpted.

```
MATCH (ur:UR { id: "arqz12a" })
WITH ur, SUM(ur.oc) as count
WHERE count = 9
WITH ur, count
RETURN count, ur.urid;
```

Comment: What is your graph model. How do you have many users with the same id?

Comment: In line 1 you specified the node id as "arq12a". Thus it will only get the sum of a single node

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you are not selecting the urid but the node "ur" in line 2. Thus it will not sum up the total properly.  Try below query.

```
MATCH (ur:UR )
WITH ur.urid as urid, SUM(ur.oc) as count
WHERE count = 9
RETURN count, urid;
```

To debug it, run below query and you will see that the sum is not working well without ur.urid on line 2.

```
MATCH (ur:UR { id: "arqz12a" })
WITH ur, SUM(ur.oc) as count
RETURN ur, count
```